# Mapping Foreign Key Object after Insert

Tags: c#, automapper, mediatr

When inserting a new record the requirement is to return a DTO with either a simplified FK object or a full FK object included in the expected output.

The problem is the related objects ExampleOptionDto and ExampleOptionSimpleDto are always null.

What am I doing wrong?

// Expected Output

```json
{
    "Id": 45,
    "Name": "Example...",
    "ExampleOptionSimple": {
        "Id": 45,
        "Name": "Example Option 7"
    },
    "ExampleOption": {
        "Id": 45,
        "Name": "Example Option 7",
        "Acronym": "",
        ...
    }
}
```

// Create Handler

```cs
public class Create
{
    public class Command : IRequest<ExampleDto>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ExampleOptionId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Handler : BaseHandler, IRequestHandler<Command, ExampleDto>
    {
        public Handler(ApplicationContext db, IMapper mapper, IUserContext userContext) : base(db, mapper, userContext) {}

        public async Task<ExampleDto> Handle(Command command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ExampleEntity entity = Mapper.Map<Command, ExampleEntity>(command);
            await Db.ExampleEntity.AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);
            await Db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            
            ExampleDto model = Mapper.Map<ExampleEntity, ExampleDto>(entity);
            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

// DTOs

```cs
public class ExampleDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ExampleOptionId { get; set; }

    // Use this to return a simple related model with just Id & Name
    public ExampleOptionSimpleDto ExampleOptionSimple { get; set; }

    // Use this to return the full related object and all properties
    public ExampleOptionDto ExampleOption { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleOptionDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Guid? DeletedBy { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleOptionSimpleDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

// Mappings

```cs
CreateMap<ExampleOption, ExampleOptionSimpleDto>();
CreateMap<ExampleOption, ExampleOptionDto>();
CreateMap<ExampleEntity, ExampleDto>();
```

// Test

```cs
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(CreateTestData))]
public async Task Create_Adds_Record_To_Store_And_Returns_It(Create.Command cmd)
{
    // Create a new record
    ExampleDto exampleDto = await _fixture.SendAsync(cmd, _accessor);
    exampleDto.ShouldNotBeNull(); // Passes
    exampleDto.Id.ShouldBe(1); // Passes
    
    exampleDto.ExampleOption.ShouldNotBeNull(); // Fails
    exampleDto.ExampleOptionSimple.ShouldNotBeNull(); // Fails
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you've written makes sense to me, I just have two suggestions

**1)**    Debug the hell out of your command handler. Specifically what's being stored in each value here

```
ExampleEntity entity = Mapper.Map<Command, ExampleEntity>(command);
await Db.ExampleEntity.AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);
await Db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        
ExampleDto model = Mapper.Map<ExampleEntity, ExampleDto>(entity);
```

**2.** Try adding an another mapping from your dto to entity

```
CreateMap<ExampleDto ,ExampleEntity>();
```

Comment: Tried debugging and the additional mapping but still can't find the problem

Comment: Hmm, what about adding the reverse mappings for CreateMap<ExampleOption, ExampleOptionSimpleDto>() & CreateMap<ExampleOption, ExampleOptionDto>();